# Customizing SearchBox in SharePoint 2013 Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, master-page, css, branding, search-box

[image]

My customer is not happy with the current position of the **SearchBox**. So My job is to move it in the **X** (`o365cs-nav`) or in the **Y** (`ms-cui-TabRowRight`) position. I am looking for these positions in `seattle.html` master page.

Yet to find any workaround or these positions.

I know the position/location of the SearchBox in `seattle.html`. Desperately need the position of **X** or **Y**

Comment: look for an id of DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea and reposition it to your liking?

Comment: `DeltaPlaceHolderSearchArea` is the SearchBox. I need to find the **X** or **Y**. Thanks @EricAlexander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The elements in positions `X` and `Y` which you are looking for are generated on the fly. You will not find the `source` of them in the `seattle.html`.

**Position X**: Its nothing but inside the `SuiteBar` which lies in div with ID `ms-designer-ribbon`.

source in seattle.html

[image]

Above image clearly indicates that there is no source for what you are looking.

The generated html for suite bar looks something like below

[image]

**Position Y**: This is again similar to `X` inside div with Id `ms-designer-ribbon`, which is generated on run time.

**Solution**: You can set the display attribute of the current OOB positioned `search box` in master page to `none`. Then write a simple `JavaScript` to change the position and make it visible.

Comment: How can I move it to **X** or **Y**?

Comment: See the solution I have written.. You can do it with the help `JavaScript`.

Comment: Do you mean adding some css by **Then write a simple JavaScript to change the position and make it visible**

Comment: Yes. First you set `display:none` on the existing search box. This is because you would not want to show to user the effect while search box changes its position. i.e initially at oob position, then your `javascript` changes it to some other position. Its better to hide it at first instance when all the processing is done, then show it to users.

Comment: In that case I can add some css in master page. It will not show the transition I guess.

Comment: Yes thats perfect.

Comment: **Changing the position by css only** I don't like. Have to consider so many screen. Thought that there will be a way to move the **SearchBox** html to **X** or **Y** position. Anyway, thanks for your time.

Comment: Don't change the position with `css`. But instead move the entire search box into the div which you want. i.e. first get html using `jQuery.html()` and then append it to destination div using `jQuery.append()`